# Getting "incompatible types: expected an 'isolated' function" when trying to filter records in ballerina

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

I am trying to filter `User` records in Ballerina. My code is similar to this.

```ballerina
type User record {|
    string id;
    string name;
    int age;
|};

int votingAge = 18;

public isolated function someFunc() returns error? {
    User[] users = [
        {id: "1", name: "John", age: 13},
        {id: "2", name: "Doe", age: 23},
        {id: "3", name: "Adam", age: 19}
    ];
    
    User[] eligibleVoters = users.filter(user => user.age >= votingAge);
}
```

Here I am getting `incompatible types: expected an 'isolated' function` error for the following argument `user => user.age >= votingAge`. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice you are calling the `filter()` langlib function inside an 'isolated' function.

If you check the go-to definition of the langlib function (https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/blob/196825363e81a17f4f71c837bb010046edb5cad4/langlib/lang.array/src/main/ballerina/array.bal#L130), take note of the `@isolatedParam` annotation. This annotation mandates that the provided argument function must also be marked as `isolated` if the langlib function is called within an isolated context.

What you are doing is equivalent to,

```ballerina
User[] eligibleVoters = users.filter(isolated function(User user) returns boolean {
        return user.age >= votingAge;
    });
```

Here you are trying to access a mutable value `votingAge` inside an 'isolated' function.
Therefore, you need to make it immutable.

Making it, final or a constant will fix the issue.
i.e. `final int votingAge = 18;` or `const int votingAge = 18;` would fix the issue.